# UIScrollView with background image

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I want to have a background image behind a UIScrollView area. That part's easy. The issue I'm running into is I don't want the image to move. I want it to fill the screen and then the scrolling just happens over that without effecting the image in anyway.

I've looked through lots of other postings on similar topics, but can't seem to get anything to work.

When I do the following, the background scrolls:

```
CGRect fullScreenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
UISCrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImageView *bkg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]];
[scrollView addSubview:bkg];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the image in a UIImageView and place it behind the UIScrollView. Set the UIScrollView's color to 100% transparency (`[UIColor clearColor]`).

Comment: what do you mean by behind? subView?

Comment: Not a subview. The scrollview and the image view are siblings, and the image view is place behind the scrollview. Check out `insertSubView:belowSubView:`.

Comment: interesting. I think I'm doing something wrong still. I'm setting the view for my uiviewcontroller to the scrollview. Then I tried the insertSubView:belowsubview with the image, but the scrollview isn't a subview so it ends up scrolling the image still.

Comment: got it... I was doing all this work in the wrong place. I moved the code from loadView to viewDidLoad and called the super first and everything works now. thanks!

Comment: Don't set the view of UIViewController to UIScrollView. Restore it to UIView, and subview a UIScrollView and UIImageView.