# add ImageView at the background of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift2

i am trying to create a mechanism for changing user's profile image same as whatsapp does , here's how it looks :

this is what i want to achieve

[image: image1]

and this is what i have :

[image]

in the second image the background of scrollView is in purple colour i want to add here a UIImageView + UIEffectView as shown in the first image which will be immovable (fixed at position ) but i dont know where to start if anybody knows how am gonna do this than please let me know it'll be so helpful for me.  thanks

Comment: Just add another UIImageView as a subview of the UIScrollView.

Comment: yeah i tried this but its affecting the  scrolling and zooming of my central imageView making it dysfunctional @BrettDonald

Comment: Okay, so according to this thread, you need to place the UIImageView *behind* the UIScrollView, and make the background of the UIScrollView transparent. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10826134/2518285

Comment: Okay let me try this